# How to insert backslashes before all line breaks in a string?

Tags: php

I am building multi-line strings in PHP that need to be used in Javascript functions, so I `echo` out the strings and they appear where they should, but the problem I'm having is that Javascript multi-line strings must have a backslash `\` at the end of each line.

Aside from hard-coding the backslashes in (which I can't do since the strings are used outside of the Javascript functions, too) how can I add a backslash before each line break in the string?

Comment: http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php or http://ca3.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str_replace("\r\n","\\\r\n",$str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the string through the `json_encode` function to generate a JavaScript string. Don't try to write your own routine to make a string safe for JS.

Comment: Genius! Didn't come out with this way! Thanks!