# adding a full stop after each line in a string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have PHP script that collect the email body in specific format save it in a string in a specific format as follow:

```
Name1: qqqq wwww eeee rrrr  
Name2: rrrr tttt yyyy  
name3: iiii oooo pppp aaaa  
name4: ssss dddd ffff gggg  
name5: hhhh jjjj kkkk
```

what I need is adding a "." after each line to become like this

```
Name1: qqqq wwww eeee rrrr.  
Name2: rrrr tttt yyyy.  
and so on
```

the problem is the names are always changing so I think I cant use replace command because of this.

Comment: It would help if you could show us your code

Comment: You do not even need a regex, all you need is to add `.` before a `\n` (with `str_replace`), and then just append `.` to the end of the string.

Comment: You don't even need `regex` for this task. If you build the output in a string you can `str_replace("\n", ".\n")` to add the full stops after the processing or you can insert them as you build each line.

Comment: Near duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13533606/2943403

Comment: @Wiktor this feels rather abandoned.  Do you have anything to close this with?

Comment: @mickmackusa Let's close with "What does this regex mean"? Actually, it is off-topic for me. Let's ask in the SO Close Vote Reviewers room But please cast an off-topic vote (No code supplied...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was no coding attempt supplied.  Sometimes _Too Broad_ is used to close _No Attempt_ questions. Just as easily could be closed as _Off-topic: recommend a tutorial_ because it is asking for a new/complete solution to be written as opposed to fixing a coding issue/error.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex.
You can use str_replace and replace "new line" with "dot new line" and just add a dot at the end of the string since last line does not have  a new line.

```
$str = 'Name1: qqqq wwww eeee rrrr
Name2: rrrr tttt yyyy
name3: iiii oooo pppp aaaa
name4: ssss dddd ffff gggg
name5: hhhh jjjj kkkk';

Echo str_replace(PHP_EOL, "." . PHP_EOL, $str) . ".";
```

https://3v4l.org/oi1HG

The benefit of not using regex is that it's probably faster and uses less memory.

Comment: Take care that `PHP_EOL` is OS specific. So a line ending with `\n` doesn't match `PHP_EOL` in a Windows environment.